# Unable to download [file] from [server] Unable to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, streaming

I am using the following asp.net code to stream word documents.

```
     Response.Clear();
     Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Letter.WordFileName.Replace(" ", "%20").Replace("&", "And") + "\"");
     Response.BinaryWrite(Letter.WordDocument.ToMSWordDocument());
     Response.End();
```

Last week, I started to receive the following message while trying to stream files in ie8

> Unable to download [file] from [server]
>
> Unable to open this Internet site.  The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be     >found.  Please try again later.

I do not get the error after updating to ie9 but most of my users still use ie8. I have a feeling this might be related to a windows security patch, but I have not found anything like this from my Google searches.

Here is some more information:

- The error only happens in ie8
- I am not using https to display a  word document
- The problem started happening last week.
- The error exists on systems that have not been updated for 3 weeks.
- I have this issue on multiple computers using ie8.

Response Header

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie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path=/
    content-disposition: attachment;filename="Septa%20Roberts%20Compound%2020111226[1].doc"
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2012 16:07:51 GMT
    Content-Length: 147456

Comment: Have you tried to use the same code you're using to output the content to the Response stream to write a file on the server and then attempt to use IE8 to download the created file? That would be a good starting point to be able to use Fiddler to watch the HTTP requests for the static file and your dynamic download script.

Comment: Using Response.AddHeader "Cache-control", "no-cache" anywhere? And some other ideas to try: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/error-message-unable-to-open-this-internet-site/758f7a64-b081-4981-814f-9a7a53434fb8

Comment: @brad can you make a test to change the file name to a simple file name with out bracket and spaces to see if its works ?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
Response.End();
```

with

```
Response.Flush
CompleteRequest()
```

in the end of the code block (refer [here](http://ardalis.com/Use-HttpApplication.CompleteRequest-Instead-of-Response.End) and [there](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx) for extra info). Maybe the Response redirect has some kind of trouble and it causes your server's response to fail on browser's eyes.

Comment: I sponsored a bounty for this question because I believe we have the same problem with one of our customers. We do not have access to the customer's internal network and we can not reproduce the problem ourselves. Sadly the person who asked the question did not pay any attention to it so nobody can validate the answer easily :(

I awarded the bounty which was about to expire anyway to this answer not because it fixed the issue but because it was really educational (check the sources).

Comment: The first link shared by Alfabravo was really helpful and solved my issue. It was about IE and https combo. This answer is really good.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I found out that a security patch for asp.net changes the headers which somehow leads to this behavior in IE8. More info here: [CLICK](http://www.asprangers.com/post/2012/01/24/Stream-rendering-failing-for-PDF-Excel-Docs-after-MS11-100-patch-from-Aspx-pages.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is doing because the browser has something that is causing this do any other workstations have this issue in trying to access this site in IE 8 ?

1) Check for Malware using 
       - SpyBot-Search & Destroy - http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html
       - Adware - http://www.lavasoft.nu/home.php

2) Do you have any extra antiviruses installed or firewalls installed if so what are they ? They might need to be uninstalled completely at least on a temp basis to try and figure out what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try to do is to upload a word document to another server and download it using IE8 while fiddler is running. Then have a look at the response header and see what's missing / different in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this and give it a try:

```
// check for IE
if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE")
{
  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
  Response.AppendHeader(@"Pragma", @"no-cache");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the root, don't use this guys unless you really know how to tackle the situation for IE8(actually I just happen to find out it's only happening in IE8), remove this if you using it :

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

and this line in your code :

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", " no-store, no-cache ");
```

Thanks to the author :

> http://www.asprangers.com/post/2012/01/24/Stream-rendering-failing-for-PDF-Excel-Docs-after-MS11-100-patch-from-Aspx-pages.aspx

---

Just found this, might help as well ;

**Beware the ASP.NET SetCacheability method**

HttpCacheability enum on **MSDN**:

**NoCache**: nobody can cache the page.

**Private**: only browsers can cache it (but not shared proxies). This is the default value

**Public**: everybody can cache the page, proxies included

**Server**: pages are cached only on the server (like the NoCache, so browsers don't cache the page)

**ServerAndNoCache**: Server and NoCache... the same as Server

**ServerAndPrivate**: Server and Private... the same as Private

> http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/04/01/Beware-the-ASP.NET-SetCacheability-method.aspx